# DataGridView image column is not updating

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I use the following code to update the DataGridView image column. It works with all other columns but it doesn't change the image column.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row1 in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
  Image imageFile = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\Hewad\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Exchange\\Exchange\\Resources\\icons\\icons8_checkmark_20px.png");
  row1.Cells[0].Value = imageFile;
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365965/how-do-i-add-an-image-in-my-datagridviewimagecolumn

Comment: @UthistranSelvaraj That link isn't really helpful.  The user is already setting the Value with an image.

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: Does your DataGridView use a DataSource?  You need to document that.

Comment: Note that you do not need multiple instances of the same image for each row.  Create one single `Image` and assign it multiple time either to the control or the DataSource.  Also, if it was an actual embedded resource you could pull it from there rather than the file system.

Comment: Yes I use a data source for my datagridview

Comment: Then you need to give us that information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The below will work. the cell must be an image cell (`DataGridViewImageCell`)to accept the image.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row1 in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
  Image imageFile = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\Hewad\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Exchange\\Exchange\\Resources\\icons\\icons8_checkmark_20px.png");
  DataGridViewImageCell imagecell = new DataGridViewImageCell();
  imagecell.Value = imageFile;
  row1.Cells[0] = imagecell;
}
```